# Getting data from the localhost

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a project using Angular 4. The part that I have problem is: There are so many schools and each school has a Id number and the school may have one or many images. I want to get the each school with its `"kampus_id"` and the show its image(s).

I can get the url and show the image but i understand that how many image(s) the school has. And show every imags is the slider. My code is:

Environment URL: `resimUrl: 'http://localhost/mebresim/'`

#### .ts file :

```js
 data.attributes.photo = environment.resimUrl + data.attributes.kampus_id + '.jpg';
```

#### .HTML file :

```
<ngb-carousel>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-full" [src]="navbar.infoData.attributes.photo" alt="Okul Fotoğrafı Bulunamadı">
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-full" [src]="navbar.infoData.attributes.photo" alt="Okul Fotoğrafı Bulunamadı">
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-full" [src]="navbar.infoData.attributes.photo" alt="Okul Fotoğrafı Bulunamadı">
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Now lets say that the school with an `"kampus_id" = 12`  has images like 12.jpg, 12_1.jpg and 12_2.jpg.

How should change my code to show all images in slider?

[image: data.attributes]

Comment: save images into array and use `ngFor` to loop over the array

Comment: you can use a method to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to iterate over all photos saved in data.attributes.photos, and generate a separate slide for each one.

TypeScript:

`data.attributes.photos = [ "12.jpg", "12_1.jpg", "12_2.jpg" ]`

HTML:

```
<ngb-carousel>
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let photo of navbar.infoData.attributes.photos">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-full" [src]="photo" alt="Okul Fotoğrafı Bulunamadı">
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Comment: Thank you. But i dont know the number of images of the school. It could be one, three or five. every school is different.

Comment: Could you please show more of the data structure? Where do you store school data? From the typescript fragment you provide, I can guess that the data variable holds info for a specific school, but where do you store all schools data variables? It would be more helpful if you provide the code of your component, instead of only including a part of it.

Comment: Yes. Well inside the attributes i have many information of the school.see the the screenshot. The name of the images are assigned with an id. But every school has one or more images. If it was a constant number then your method works perfect but it may be one image or 10.

Comment: and the photos are in my local PC inside a folder called mebresim. Its url is given in environment.

Comment: Did you get it? @Chop

Comment: myads, if you want to show variable number of photos, you will need an HTTP server that would scan school's photos directory and return them back to your Angular interface. In your Angular code you could generate a service that would make an HTTP GET request to the HTTP server running on your localhost machine. Once the request is resolved, you will save the data in data.attributes.photos, and the slider will update itself automatically. P.S. it is impossible to do this with Angular alone because of browser security mechanism preventing JavaScript code from accessing your file system.